# Subtable inside a table / Adjusting table column width on the fly

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

I've been fiddling with the following table for a while, and have some minor issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \caption{
  \textbf{Pheno file format}}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}\hline\hline
\textbf{Pheno file headers} &   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Notes}} \\ \hline\hline
sex                &   \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{The sex column is restricted to the following values.} \\ \hline\hline
                   &   \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Sex}    & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}|}{Value} \\ \hline\hline
                   &   Male                         & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}|}{1}                               \\ \hline
                   &   \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Female} & \multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}|}{2}    \\ \hline
                   &   \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Missing}& \multicolumn{1}{|p{1cm}|}{-1}   \\ \hline
studyid            &   \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{1}{*}{Description of the study the data belongs to - eg. 'Hapmap6.0'.}} \\
                   &   \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{If studyid is not given, 'unknown' is used.} \\ \hline
studyid            &   \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{Description of the study the data belongs to - eg. 'Hapmap6.0'.
                                       If studyid is not given, 'unknown' is used.} \\ \hline
%\cline{3-4}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Questions:

1. So, I'm sort of embedding a subtable inside a table. I first had
   it as a separate table, but then I stuck it inside the main table.
   It is the table with headers `Sex` and `Value`. It would be nice if
   I could adjust the width of the third margin so that it was only as
   wide as necessary, and also if all the lines to the left of that
   table, starting with the double line under `Sex/Value` were not
   present. The other problem is that the numbers in the third column
   are not left justified. So I'd like it to look something like

   > ```
   >  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   > | Pheno file headers  |                    Notes                             |
   > ==============================================================================
   > | sex                 | The sex column is restricted to the following values |
   > ==============================================================================
   >                       | Sex    |  Value |
   >                       | Male   |    1   |
   >                       | Female |    2   |
   >                       | Missing|   -1   |
   > ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   > | Studyid             | Some stuff                                           |
   > ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   > ```

   Can this be done without lots of complexity?
2. I've got two examples of a cell (starting with studyid) across two rows and two columns. I think I prefer the one at the bottom. Is that the best way to do it? It certainly seems simpler than the one above it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps a suggestion, but here is an alternative to your current set up. I've used [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to allow for variable-width `tabular` columns (via column type `X`), filling up to some fixed with using the `tabularx` environment. Additionally, [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) provide a cleaner spread of tables vertically, while virtually restricting the use of vertical rules (due to the rule definitions). Either way, the tabular layout helps columnar alignment, which removes the requirement for using vertical rules anyway.

The interior `tabular` has been adjusted to provide a natural-width horizontal alignment, as suggested in your ASCII-art interpretation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage[labelfont=normal,font=bf]{caption}%http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \caption{Pheno file format}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
      \toprule
      \textbf{Pheno file headers} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Notes}} \\
      \midrule
      sex                         & The sex column is restricted to the following values: \\[\jot]
                                  & \begin{tabular}{lc}
                                      Sex     & Value \\ \midrule
                                      Male    & $\phantom{-}1$ \\
                                      Female  & $\phantom{-}2$ \\
                                      Missing & $-1$
                                    \end{tabular} \\[\jot]
      \midrule
      studyid                     & Description of the study the data belongs to - eg. \texttt{Hapmap6.0}. \\
                                  & If studyid is not given, \texttt{unknown} is used. \\
      \midrule
      studyid                     & Description of the study the data belongs to - eg. \texttt{Hapmap6.0}. \\
                                  & If studyid is not given, \texttt{unknown} is used. \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Using `\phantom{-}` leaves the correct amount of horizontal (and vertical) space for `-` without actually typesetting it. That allows for aligning the entries within the nested `tabular` while also centering it.

`\jot` is a length of `3pt`. Using it together with `\\`, as in `\\[\jot]`, pushes the `tabular` line break down vertically by `3pt`. Using a length register (like `\jot`) is preferred over explicitly using `\\[3pt]`, since you can modify `\jot` (using, say `\setlength{\jot}{5pt}`) in one location and it would take effect wherever it is used *after* the redefinition, rather than having to manually modify the `3pt` vertical skip everywhere.

Layout changes to the nested/interior `tabular` is possible (for example, if you want it horizontally centered within the outer `tabularx`, although the existing alignment seems sufficient).

Finally, there's no need to use [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) anymore, more obvious reasons. In my opinion, the input code is simpler and easier to follow.

Comment: Nice layout. I didn't know you could nest `tabular` environments like that. It's not necessary to repeat the studyid line twice. It is exactly the same, right? Can you elaborate on the use of `\phantom` and `\jot`? It seems the cognoscenti don't like vertical lines. Are they considered cluttery?

Comment: +1: I think it might be worth using `\usepackage[labelfont=normal,font=bf]{caption}` rather than manually specifying the caption font using `\textbf`

Comment: @FaheemMitha: True, it is not necessary to repeat the `studyid` line twice. I did it, because you supplied it in your MWE. `;)` Nesting a `tabular` inside a `tabular` (`tab`-ception? he he) is one way of subdividing cells, while `\multicolumn` is typically used for cell merging. I'll add some description about `\phantom`&`\jot`.The vertical rule issue is, as I mentioned in my answer, due to the fact that you're already organizing things in columns. As such the vertical nature of the columns already denote a division between "elements," making the use of forced vertical rules somewhat obsolete.

Comment: @Werner: made the `caption` edit- if it's not appropriate, please role back